# How to keep google fonts in assets folder

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I have this link in my `styles.scss`

[@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');](http://@import%20url(%27https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open%20Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap%27);)

it is working fine in locally, but on production this API fails, or it is blocked, how can I host it in my project itself so that this API hit dependency get removed?

Is there any way to do the same for above URL?

Comment: So if you want to host it locally, just go to google fonts page and download font package

Comment: @Justinas I am new in ANgular I don't know how to download and use it in my project

Comment: download the font you want to use and use CSS `@font-face` to import the font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open [your link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open%20Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap) in web browser then you see this
[image]

then download each font then save to your folder assert.

example : https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v20/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bf8pkAp6a.woff2

then in  tag or css file, edit src to the path you save the font

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(path/to/your/font/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bf8pkAp6a.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
```

Comment: I will store this files in assets folder, and mention those things in global stye,scss, how can I write path in SRC?

Comment: @techguy save all content from your link in to a css file (example font.css), then edit url in that file. append that file to your html as you add other css file.

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts).

You can download font files and include them in your project.